# Debugging new crossval function: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging, cross-validation

I've been writing a crossval() function on my own since the `crossval()` on `MATLAB` doesn't really allow me to experiment with different(custom ) loss/error measures. However, the loss_estimate that I get seem to be very small and I am not able to figure out what goes wrong here.

The code I used is below:

```
function Loss_est = CV(fun1,fun2,data,k)
K = crossvalindex(data,k);
Loss = zeros(size(K,2),1);
for j1 = 1:size(K,2)
    Xtest = K{j1};
    Xtest = [ones(size(Xtest,1),1) Xtest(:,1:end-1)];
    ytest = Xtest(:,end);
    K1 = K;
    K1{j1}=[];
    Xtrain = cell2mat(K1(1,:)');
    Xtrain = [ones(size(Xtrain,1),1) Xtrain(:,1:end-1) ]; 
    ytrain = Xtrain(:,end);
    ynew = Xtest*fun1(ytrain,Xtrain);
    Loss(j1,1) = fun2(ynew,ytest);
end
Loss(isnan(Loss))=[];
Loss_est = mean(Loss);
```

Here, corssvalindex function take the data and partitions the data into cells after randomizing the rows of the data.

```
%% Temp_crossvalidation indexing
function [K,edges] = crossvalindex(data,k)
r = size(data,1);
id = randperm(r);
data_1 = data(id,:);

% Edges
edges = 1:round(r/k):r+1;
if numel(edges) < k+1
    edges = [edges r+1];
end

% Index-ed and partition
[~,idx] = histc(id,edges);
K = cell(1,numel(edges-1));
for i = 1:numel(edges-1)
    K{i} = data_1(idx == i,:);
end

end
```

Loss estimates seem to be too small. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

```
data = randi(1000,100,10);
fun1 = @(x,y) regress(x,y);
fun2 = @(x,y) sum(abs(y-x));

k = 10;
Loss_est = CV(fun1,fun2,data,k);
Loss_est =

   5.4346e-26
```

Comment: I think you need to post the code for `crossvalindex` as well. Also a side note, `fun1` and `fun2` are terrible input argument names! why not `fun_train` or `fun_model` and `fun_err` or something?

Comment: Also have you debugged and checked the values of the `Loss` matrix before you delete the `NaN` values?

Comment: Hey Dan. Check out the code for `crossvalindex`. 

Lol. I'll think about renaming the whole thing.